# Counting the posts of a custom Wordpress loop (WP_Query)?

Tags: loop

I tried tplacing this:

```
    <?php $count = count($custom_posts); ?>
    <h2><?php echo $count; ?></h2>
```

at the end of the loop:

```
      <?php if ( bbp_get_forum_title() == 'Test Forum 1' ) : ?>
            <?php $custom_posts = new WP_Query(); ?>
            <?php $custom_posts->query('post_type=blocks&location=Business and Finance&order=DESC'); ?>
            <?php while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="ad">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $count = count($custom_posts); ?>
                <h2><?php echo $count; ?></h2>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

But instead of the total of posts, I getting this output:

> Translation 1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim 1

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Correct way of getting the total number of posts is:

```
<?php $count = $custom_posts->found_posts; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties

Edit: acknowledging @Kresimir Pendic's answer as probably correct.  `post_count` is the count of posts for that particular page, while `found_posts` is the count for all available posts that meets the requirements of the query without pagination.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Thanks! Hey one last question. How can I use that number to make an if statement which is out of that loop (before of the loop). Because it seems like the number is only displayed when I place the variable after that loop.

Comment: You can put the $count = $custom_posts->post_count just after the  $custom_posts->query(). Note that $custom_posts->post_count only gets you the number of results in that 'page' of the result set. If you need to get the total number of results in the 'whole' result set, use $custom_posts->found_posts.

Comment: This answer is most likely not correct for most situations. Use found_posts (all found posts) instead of post_count (number of posts to display on this page). This comment is redundant logically speaking, but not socially speaking.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `$custom_posts->post_count` will return the amount of posts shown on this page, so it will display either the `posts_per_page` value of the query or a lower value if the amount remaining to show is lower.

the correct answer should be `<@kresimir-pendic>`'s answer that uses `$custom_posts->found_posts`

Comment: Life saver. Till now I have been using another query to find posts without pagination

Answer (score 60):

Manny linked correct documentation page but `post_count` is wrong.
To get total number of posts `WP_Query` returns use "found_posts"

```
<?php

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$total = $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer.

Comment: I also reconfirm that this the correct answer. This should be accepted.

Comment: I can confirm the confirmation that this answer is in fact true. As is the re-confirmation

Comment: In confirming the confirmation of the most recent confirmation I have determined that the original confirmation is indeed confirmed, as is the confirmation after that one.

Comment: @Bysander stated that he "*can* confirm the confirmation..." but did not actually confirm. Therefore, I write to confirm that I am **unconfirming** the confirming of his alleged confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

Or this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = $query->post_count;
```