# Count custom posts type and filter by tag

Tags: php, wp-query

I'm using this code to count the number of posts of a specific custom post type that have also a specific tag:

```
<?php 
    
    //Array
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cars',
        'tag' => 'available'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $loop->have_posts() ) :
         $count_posts = wp_count_posts("cars")->publish;
?>

<?php
        echo "<p>Total:  $count_posts cars</p>";
    else:
?>   
<?php
    echo "<p>No cars available.</p>";
?>
<?php 
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

However the loop does not filter out the posts under "available" tag, but it just takes all the posts under "cars" post type.

Probably I'm close to the solution but I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27117/35799)

Comment: `wp_count_posts` isn't using your query, it's independently counting how many instances of the "cars" post type there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_count_posts` is not affect your custom query. You can use `found_posts` to return the number of posts from the custom query. So try to change the code after your loop query as follows. Hope it helps.

```
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    $count_posts = $loop->found_posts;
    echo "<p>Total:  $count_posts cars</p>";
else :
    echo "<p>No cars available.</p>";
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help!